# Pdf button not showing of datatable in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have this table in HTML file. I want to show PDF button above datatable to export this in PDF file.

```
<table class="viewCustomerDatatable table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" cellspacing="0" 
    width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Person</th>
            <th>E-Mail<br/>Phone</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Update Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

         -------code goes here for table-------
        </tbody>
 </table>
```

I am calling this in jquery:

```
$('.viewCustomerDatatable').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    "buttons": [
        {
            extend: 'collection',
            text: 'Export',
            buttons: [
                'copy',
                'excel',
                'csv',
                'pdf',
                'print'
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

I want to show the PDF button but its not showing.

How to do this thing work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which datatable library are you using?

Comment: When you click on the `Export` button (to display the button collection), are you saying it only displays the other 4 buttons? Everything except the PDF button?

Comment: Also, have you double-checked that you have included [all the required libraries](https://datatables.net/download/) for buttons?

Comment: Yes I have included all the libraries for button.

Comment: Copy, csv and print are working. But pdf button is not showing

Comment: I'm using latest version of datable

Comment: @pawads: Could you show us the libraries you're including, please?

Comment: I'm using this one: https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js